# Statistics on database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've thought of creating a MySQL table with the following structure:

```
id  |   date   |   page_address   |    ip_array
1   | 12-12-12 |  /page.php       | ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4
```

Then for each visited page in my website, it would:

- check for the row containing today's date and current page (if there is none, insert one).
- check if the visitor's ip is included in the field `ip_array`, if it's not, then include it.

After this, I'll have a statistic of how many different visitors I've had in each page and each day.

Is it an acceptable way of doing this?

Comment: A table with all the page addresses, and then a seperate table with a row for every hit with a date/ip address/foreign key to the first table would be a better way of approaching that, rather than using a comma seperated list of IP addresses.

Comment: If you are looking to re-invent the wheel, or need absolute accurate results, sure.  However if you just want page view statistics, Google Analytics is what you want (and free)  http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: Analytics is good too, but the statistics shown in there are not accurate to the current minute, you have to wait for it to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, `ip_array` is not a good idea, you'd better do one record for one ip.

```
id  |   date   |   page_address   | ip
1   | 12-12-12 |  /page.php       | ip1
2   | 12-12-12 |  /page.php       | ip2
3   | 12-12-12 |  /page.php       | ip3
4   | 12-12-12 |  /page.php       | ip4
```

Then you can do a simple SELECT to count the number of different visitors for each page and each day.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE date = ? AND page_address = ?
```

Even you can let page_address detail store in another table, and use an page_id to relate them.

**table1:**

```
id  |   date   |  page_id  | ip
1   | 12-12-12 |  1        | ip1
2   | 12-12-12 |  1        | ip2
3   | 12-12-12 |  1        | ip3
4   | 12-12-12 |  1        | ip4
```

**table2:**

```
id  | page_address 
1   | /page.php      
2   | /page2.php
```

Then you do do a SELECT like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 
ON table1.page_id = table2.id 
WHERE table1.date =? AND table2.page_address = ?
```

Comment: You could perhaps add another column for page visits from each ip, so that if the ip has visited the page 10 times, you can know that as well.

Comment: @AnPel That depends on needs.